# How do I cut a single large file into manageable chunks by regex?

Tags: regular-expression, save

I currently have a single file that has nearly 10000 lines of text in it. Each section that I want is broken up like so -

```
Chapter 1: Chapter 1
TEXT GOES HERE
Chapter 2: Chapter 2
TEXT GOES HERE
Chapter 3: Chapter 3
TEXT GOES HERE
```

I want to break up each chapter so that I save a file like 01.tex, 02.tex, and 03.tex that contains all of that text for that chapter. Is there a way to regex through the file and make a save for each chapter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a job for `:global`, with which you can split the file into ranges, here from a line starting with `Chapter` to the one before the next such line. To correctly handle the last range, insert a dummy line containing `EOF` at the end first.

To build the filespec, I would usually use `:execute`, but that doesn't handle ranges. So, I use the more obscure *backtick expression* (`` :help `= ``). Instead of a variable counter, I just grab the first number from the current (first of the range) line:

```
:global/^Chapter/,/^Chapter\|^EOF/-1write `='path/to/dir' . matchstr(getline('.'), '\d\+') . '.tex'`
```

This basically searches for all lines starting with `Chapter`, and then `:write` the following range: `.,/^Chapter\|^EOF/-1` (the `.` is implicit by the positioning of `:global`).

Comment: Could you explain that semicolon? I'd have expected a <kbd>.</kbd> there to denote the current line (which is the line matching ^Chapter), and can't really find out what a semicolon does there (usually, it repeats f,F,t,T, but that doesn't apply here, does it?). Also, couldn't you use `%:h` instead of path/to/dir?

Comment: @PhilippFrank: The semicolon is a range delimiter, see `:h :range`. It makes the search for the end start at the position of the first part of the range (with `:g`, it actually doesn't matter, and `,` would do, too). Yes, `%:h` would do; the `path/to/dir` was just an example, obviously.

Comment: Do you think you could explain how it works a bit more detail? I've read `:h :global` and `:h :range`, and I understand roughly what's happening, but I'm still having a bit of trouble parsing precisely the boundary between where the "pattern" for the global ends and where the range for the write begins.

Comment: @Rich: Yes, it's a bit cryptic. I've added some more details!

Comment: It was the implicit `.` that was stumping me. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I am most impressed by your wizardry.